# divide matlab line plot into two lines of the same colour that are not connected

Tags: matlab, plot, 2d

Hi  I have the following code that outputs the figure below. However I want to remove the green horizontal line that connects both curves on the green line.
How can  I do this and keep the same colour?
Thank you

```
Y = xlsread('hanimaadhoo_sun_path.xls','hanimaadhoo'); % 

azimuth_march_equinox = Y(1:17,1);
 altitude_march_equinox = Y(1:17,2);


 azimuth_september_equinox = Y(1:17,3);
altitude_september_equinox =Y(1:17,4);

azimuth_winter_solstice = Y(1:17,5);
altitude_winter_solstice = Y(1:17,6);

 azimuth_summer_solstice = Y(1:17,7);
altitude_summer_solstice = Y(1:17,8);

figure;
   plot(azimuth_summer_solstice,altitude_summer_solstice,azimuth_winter_solstice,altitude_winter_solstice,...
azimuth_march_equinox,altitude_march_equinox,azimuth_september_equinox,altitude_september_equinox,'LineWidth',2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should draw them as 2 separate plots. Also, you should define the color explicitly:

```
  plot(azimuth_summer_solstice,altitude_summer_solstice,...    azimuth_march_equinox,altitude_march_equinox,azimuth_september_equinox,altitude_september_equinox,'LineWidth',2);
  % Now plot winter in 2 parts!
  n = .... %Something
  plot(azimuth_winter_solstice(1:n), altitude_winter_solstice(1:n),'g','LineWidth',2);
  plot(azimuth_winter_solstice(n+1:end), altitude_winter_solstice(n+1:end),'g','LineWidth',2);
```

Be sure to fill the correct `n` before running.

Comment: hi Andrey thanks for the reply. I think the n value must be 8 since it is the 9th row that is on the other side of the graph causing the line connection problem. this doesn't seem to work however. also don't i need to "figure;" the code since at the moment I only get one graph of the last plot